# How to attach an event to a button in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

Right now I have a jQuery UI dialog with an `<iframe>` inside of the dialog. When the user pushes a button, the dialog pops up with a form-editing screen in the iframe.

Well, I want to have two buttons in the inner form-editing screen, "cancel" and "ok". Cancel doesn't save changes and closes the dialog, ok saves changes and closes the dialog. Pretty simple..

So how do I attach an event to the cancel button inside of the iframe from the parent page? I would also assume that you would somehow need to attach an event to the iframe's DOM-ready or else the button would not yet exist.

How do you do this?

Also, the iframe is on the same-domain and such so there is no cross-domain worries

A simple example is here [at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/omowi/8) with the [iframe source](http://jsbin.com/ujubi4)

Comment: Can you post some of your html structure so it is easier to mimic what you are working with?

Comment: @spin done with the complete abuse of jsbin

Comment: Ok I just posted a response. I made some jsbin samples to demonstrate but I forgot the numbers I got to. The answer should be pretty easy to follow though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so here is what I did to accomplish this. I added this code to the iframe page:

```
$(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $("#cancelbutton").click(
      function()
      {
        parent.CloseDialog();
      });
  });
```

Then in the opening page I put this:

```
function CloseDialog()
{
  $('#diag').dialog('close');
}
```

So rather than try to close the dialog from the frame I just call a method in the parent page that will take care of closing it. Same effect but a lot easier. Couldn't seem to get the frame to let me use the dialog method. But this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Does this get you close?

DialogBox.html:

```
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Edit" id="editbutton" />
    <div id="diag">
        <iframe src="/" ></iframe>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#diag').dialog({
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            autoOpen: false
        });

        $('#editbutton').click(function(){
            $('#diag iframe').attr('src','modal.html');
            $('#diag').dialog('open');
        });

        $("#diag iframe").load(function() {
            $("#diag iframe").contents().find('#cancelbutton').click(function() {
                //close dialog here
          });
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't tell where but somewhere it's getting a "Selection is null" error. And an alternative version is here: http://jsbin.com/ayoyo3/3

Comment: I believe that will do it. For iframes, it's best to use the .load() event and use .contents() to get to the source document. Easy when you think about it, but it took some thinking to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="parent.window.close();"
```

Comment: I don't want to close the parent window, only the jQueryUI dialog(which is not an actual window)